# validación condiciones CASE en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo el siguiente query

```
SELECT
C.NOMBRE,
CU.CUENTA AS [NUMERO PRODUCTO],
CU.CODIGOMENSAJE AS [CODIGO ESTADO PRODUCTO]
FROM CLIENTES C
INNER JOIN CUENTAS CU ON CU.CODIGO=C.CODIGO
```

El cual me arroja las cuentas de cada cliente y los codigos que tenga cada una de las cuentas, los codigos corresponden a si las cuentan tienen bloqueo, inactiva etc... hay algunas cuentas de clientes que como no tienen ningun mensaje estonces este campo esta vacio

el resultado de ese query es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve el cliente "EMPRESA SEIYA" tiene 2 cuentas, en una cuenta tiene 2 mensajes y en la otra tiene 3 mensajes, y el cliente "JORGE PEREZ" tiene una sola cuenta sin ningun mensaje, claro esta que hay muchos mas mensajes que puede tener una cuenta, lo que quiero es una validacion para que si una cuenta tiene dentro de todos los mensajes que tenga el codigo 11,22 entonces que diga 'CONTROLADA', si tiene varios pero dentro de esos tiene 11,22 y 41 entonces que diga 'Asegurada', y si no tiene ninguno o sale campo NULL que me diga 'ACTIVA'

osea quiero que el resultado me salga asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que se puede hacer con un CASE, pero al hacerlo siempre me salen valores repetidos

si alguien me ayuda porfa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar, por ejemplo, hacer un subselect con un APPLY(CROSS o OUTER dependiendo de si quieres que actue como inner join o como left join), en el haces un case para cuando el mensaje sea 11 le asignas 1 si es 22 asignas 2 y si es 41 asignas 3, despues haces un count distinct de esos valores, si tiene 1 o 2 entonces es controlada, si tiene 3 es asegurada y si tiene 0 entonces es activa.

```
SELECT
    C.NOMBRE,
    R.CUENTA AS [NUMERO PRODUCTO],
CASE R.CODE
    WHEN 1 THEN 'CONTROLADA'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'CONTROLADA'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'ASEGURADA'
    WHEN 0 THEN 'ACTIVA'
END AS [CODIGO ESTADO PRODUCTO]
FROM CLIENTES C
OUTER APPLY(
 SELECT 
    min(CU.CUENTA) AS CUENTA, 
    COUNT(distinct 
                CASE WHEN CU.CODIGOMENSAJE = 11 THEN 1
                WHEN CU.CODIGOMENSAJE = 22 THEN 2 
                WHEN CU.CODIGOMENSAJE = 41 THEN 3 
                ELSE NULL END
                ) AS CODE 
    FROM CUENTAS CU
 WHERE CU.CODIGO = C.CODIGO
 GROUP BY cu.cuenta
) AS R
```

Es lo mas cercano que veo para la salida que muestras que esperas.